# How to assign simply multiple return values?

Tags: tuples, variable-assignment, d, multiple-return-values

Traditionally this is done with `out` parameters, for example:

```
void notfun(ushort p, out ubyte r0, out ubyte r1)
{
    r0 = cast(ubyte)((p >> 8) & 0xFF);
    r1 = cast(ubyte)(p & 0xFF); 
}
```

With tuples it's possible to rewrite it as

```
auto fun(ushort p)
{
    import std.typecons;
    return tuple
    (
        cast(ubyte)((p >> 8) & 0xFF) ,
        cast(ubyte)(p & 0xFF)
    );
}
```

Unfortunately, the result is not assignable directly to a tuple of variable:

```
void main(string[] args)
{
    ushort p = 0x0102;
    ubyte a,b;
    // ugly brute cast!
    *(cast(ReturnType!(typeof(fun))*) &a) = fun(0x0102) ;
}
```

Is there a special syntax to allow something like

```
(a,b) = fun(0x0102);
```

or any other idiomatic way to do something similar ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to implement [PHP's `list` construct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) as a function in D:

https://github.com/CyberShadow/ae/blob/777bdecd8d81030275531bfb8a393c2bb88b3d36/utils/array.d#L434-L463

This will work for tuples and static arrays.

Comment: It looks awesome, however can it be rewritten using `std.meta` instead of your own utilities ?

Comment: Looks like the only thing you would need to do is replace `RangeTuple` with `std.typecons.staticIota`.

Comment: Thanks, this should be in phobos.

Comment: Yep, `RangeTuple` predates `staticIota`.

Comment: @CyberShadow : I'm serious when I say  that it should be in phobos. This is an excellent template. It's so clever to use `opAssign` with `auto ref` for that particular purpose...double thumb up.

Comment: @rcorre Feels hackerish as `staticIota` is not documented and has `package` access restrictions.

Comment: True, though I'm not sure what we're 'supposed' to use instead of `staticIota`. It seems like something I need rather frequently.

Comment: @rcorre Then maybe we should propose to make it public?

Comment: How do I manage to compile the `list()` template with `staticIota` if `staticIota` is reserved to phobos package ?!

Comment: @Nestedtype Currently access modifiers can be bypassed. Just use it and it will work. Don't know about the future, though.